# How to send data to API using SIM900

Tags: get, gsm, sim900

I have connected GSM SIM900 to laptop using USB-Serial converter. I have a GET API deployed on Azure. I am trying to send data to it using below AT commands:

```
AT+CCID
AT+CREG?
AT+CGATT=1
AT+CGACT=1,1

AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www"
AT+SAPBR=1,1

AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="URL", "https://<name>.azurewebsites.net/api/InjectData?d1=+11.2345+&d2=+71.12345"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
AT+HTTPTERM
```

All of the commands response with `OK` but once I send `AT+HTTPACTION=0` I get response as 603. Not able to understand this properly as the API works fine in Postman. What could be the reason for the failure?

Comment: this problem occurs most of the time for hardware issues. to ignore this you must use at least an adapter that can deliver a minimum of 2A Current. Can you share the led status of the module? and also add the current rating of the module by using an avometer with a series connection between the battery and to module. also, make sure at the same time that the API you have used doesn't require an auth key.  To check this you can use a dummy API like this:- [https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts] instead of your own API. it will help you to get closer to the problem. let me know please.

Comment: recheck that the APN you have set using the AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","www" command is correct for your mobile network provider!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reading the api response with

I think it can be used like that `AT+HTTPREAD`

```
AT+HTTPINIT
AT+HTTPPARA="URL", "https://<name>.azurewebsites.net/api/InjectData?d1=+11.2345+&d2=+71.12345"
AT+HTTPACTION=0
AT+HTTPREAD 
AT+HTTPTERM
```